How to see my dags deployed on development cluster in Airflow UI?
What configurations do I need to set in the official Airflow Helm chart to allow my dags within my Airflow git project to show in the Airflow UI deployed on my development cluster? As of now I'm testing and I know we could use git sync or add my dags to a docker image when we move to production. As of now though, I'm only able to see my dags when I deploy locally -- I'd like to see them in the UI when I deploy to the cluster.
I've tried setting this in my values.yaml file:


 

 volumeMounts:

   - name: airflow-dags

     mountPath: /opt/airflow/dags

 

 volumes:

   - name: airflow-dags

     hostPath:

       path: /Users/<myusername>/Desktop/Projects/airflow

This allows me to see it locally. Any tips?
